# Gaussian type and Euclidean sections

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I have a second question about Chapter 9 in Milman and Schechtman's book "Asymptotic theory of finite dimensional normed spaces" (first question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170654/euclidean-sections-of-normed-spaces-with-known-cotype)). It's about the proof of Theorem 9.7 (pg. 55). Here's a scan of the theorem and first paragraph of the proof.

[image: Theorem 9.7]

I don't understand the first sentence of the proof. By definition, a normed space $X$ is said to have Gaussian type $p$ constant $\alpha$ if for all $x_1, \dots, x_n \in X$, $\alpha$ is the smallest value such that:
$$\left(\mathbb{E}\|\sum_{i=1}^n g_i x_i\|^2\right)^{1/2} \leq \alpha \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \|x_i\|^p\right)^{1/p} $$ 
where the $g_i$'s are independent gaussian variables. Hence, if the type 2 constant is $\alpha$, it would imply that:
$$\mathbb{E}\|\sum_{i=1}^n g_i x_i\| \leq \alpha \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \|x_i\|^2\right)^{1/2} $$
But this inequality is in the opposite direction as that shown in the proof...

I initially thought that it's a typo, but actually, the inequality in the given direction is crucially needed later on in the proof. I'm probably missing an easy point, but somehow, I'm having trouble getting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Notice the role of $\alpha$ in the claimed inequality for $k$ - it provides a *lower* bound there. Thus, the essence of the assumption is that the type $p$ inequality does **not** hold for any smaller value of $\alpha$. Which is the same as saying that the reverse inequality holds for some collection of $n$ vectors.